# What does "a chunk of the bid is likely to have come from their own money" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean "they used their money to offset the purchasing price"?

For the Issas's purchase of Asda, a chunk of the bid is likely to have come from their own money, believes independent retail analyst Richard Hyman.

Source: https://www.bbc.com/news/business-54343391

Answer (score 1):

*a chunk of* = a non-trivial quantity / a substantial amount

In your sentence, it means that the total amount of money in the bid was a combination of personal funds (their own money) and other funds (such as private investors, corporate acquisitions, for example).

Comment: You bid on a contract. How does that involve money?

Comment: Because in this specific case, money is explicitly mentioned in the example. They're not bidding peanuts or spanners to win the contract, are they?

Comment: When you bid on a contract, that does not involve putting up money. That is precisely why I am asking you what it actually means.

Comment: You bid X to win Y. Bidding involves the use of proxy currency where it is understood that you have the means to back it up with real currency. In business transactions, you bid (what is usually understood to mean money) to acquire an item. So when Mr A and Mr B are bidding for a contract, the seller decides whose bid is more attractive. It is usually the bid which represents more money, but not necessarily so.

Comment: In theory, you could bid anything that has value when a seller has indicated that alternatives to money are also accepted in a bid. For example, let's say an art dealer is selling a painting I want and they have an auction. I might bid 1 million dollars plus a unique painting that I own. My bid consists of money+valuable item. The unique painting has value to them, making my bid attractive.